# Using MVVM, how can I dynamically generate view by using App.config

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have application with two views in a separate xaml files (FirstView.xaml and SecondView.xaml). In the default mode the application generates the view from FirstView.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfDemo.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDemo"
         StartupUri="View\FirstView.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

I can switch to the second view by editing the line:

```
StartupUri="View\SecondView.xaml"
```

This works fine on compile time but I would like to achieve this on run time. I created application settings with the following contents:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <WpfDemo.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="View" serializeAs="String">
            <value>FirstView</value>
        </setting>
    </WpfDemo.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

I can read the contents of the App.config file with:

```
string view = Properties.Settings.Default.View.ToString();
```

I would like to switch the view according to the `view` variable at run time.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  I'm curious, because I'm attracted to self-destructive behavior...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step: Remove the `StartupUri` from your `App.xaml`.

Second Step: In the Code-Behind of your App.xaml do the following

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
            Uri dynamicUri = null;
            string view = Properties.Settings.Default.View.ToString();
            var result = Uri.TryCreate(view, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out dynamicUri);
            if (!result) throw new ApplicationException("Invalid settings found.");
            this.StartupUri = dynamicUri;
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
```

**Note**

The question and the answer both have nothing to do with MVVM. For such a behavior, there is no MVVM solution, since everything has to happen before we get into DataBinding or else